# Ubuntu ESM how are tokens distributed?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-advantage, esm

We are looking into getting into the Ubuntu Advantage program, especially for it's ESM program. The Ubuntu pages clearly describe how it is to be enabled on Ubuntu systems, like so:

```
sudo ubuntu-advantage enable-esm [ENTER TOKEN]
sudo apt-get update
```

We want to turn this small procedure into a simple Ansbile Role but are not sure how the tokens are distributed.

Will we get one token for the entire account (so we use this one token on many machines) or will we get multiple tokens and an individual one for each machine?

Comment: Have you [contacted](https://buy.ubuntu.com/) Canonical in this regard?

Comment: Not yet, we're doing this next. It's probably a token per machine. I'll answer my own post once we have more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We bought Ubuntu Advantage and I now have the answer to this question.

The tokens consist of a username and password, these are used to log into HTTP basic authentication when adding the repository on a machine. Every account has 1 set of a username and password to be used with all servers.

Thus they are not distributed individually, but 1 set for the entire account.

[edit] Since my writing the method has been refined. An attach method is now needed to enable ESM functionality. They no longer consist of a username and password. After using the Ubuntu Advantage token the machine is attached to you Canonical plan.